# How use UPDATE in CONCAT() of PROCEDURE MySQL

Tags: mysql, stored-procedures

I try update exist tables via PROCEDURE. But I get an error: MySQL: #1064 - You have an error in your SQL syntax; check the manual that corresponds to your MySQL server version for the right syntax to use near '= iOS, `phone_manufacture` = Apple, `phone_model` = iPhone, `os_vers` = iOS X.X' at line 1

My Procedure:

```
BEGIN 
DECLARE a, b INT;
DECLARE a1, a2, a3, a4 TEXT;
DECLARE cur1 CURSOR FOR SELECT id FROM z7_group;  
DECLARE CONTINUE HANDLER FOR NOT FOUND SET b = 1;  
OPEN cur1;   
SET b = 0; 
SET a1 = "iOS";
SET a2 = "Apple";
SET a3 = "iPhone";
SET a4 = "iOS X.X";
WHILE b = 0 DO  
FETCH cur1 INTO a;
IF b = 0 THEN
 SET @data_ all_group = (SELECT `myTables` FROM `all_group` WHERE id= a);
 SET @s = CONCAT('UPDATE ', @data_ all_group, 'SET `os` = ',a1,', `phone_manufacture` = ',a2,', `phone_model` = ',a3', `os_vers` = ',a4,');
 PREPARE stmt3 FROM @s;
 EXECUTE stmt3;
END IF;
END WHILE;
CLOSE cur1;
END;
```

Comment: Normally you can't use `;` as a delimiter if that's used in your stored procedure. I'm surprised it parsed that far.

Comment: Another thing to note is you're just jamming in arbitrary data without escaping there. That's not going to work. Use [placeholder values](https://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/5.7/en/sql-syntax-prepared-statements.html): `SET os=?,phone_manufacture=?,...` and then `EXECUTE ... USING` to bind variables. `CONCAT` is completely unnecessary here.

Comment: @tadman but if I use ALTER TABLE  instead UPDATE everything works well

Comment: Use placeholder values and see if it helps. That your table name is dynamic is a complication, but I'm sure you can deal with that.

Answer (score 0):

You have two options:
(there is more but I think it is what you want)

1. Enclose values in single quotes at inicialization:

   ```
   SET a1 = "'iOS'";
   SET a2 = "'Apple'";
   SET a3 = "'iPhone'";
   SET a4 = "'iOS X.X'";
   ```

   and fix the sentence:

   ```
   CONCAT('UPDATE ', @data_all_group, ' SET `os` = ',a1,', `phone_manufacture` = ',a2,', `phone_model` = ',a3,', `os_vers` = ',a4)
   ```

   The result will be:

   ```
   UPDATE your_table SET `os` = 'iOS', `phone_manufacture` = 'Apple', `phone_model` = 'iPhone', `os_vers` = 'iOS X.X'
   ```
2. OR: fix the query build:

   ```
    SET @s = CONCAT('UPDATE ', @data_all_group
      , "SET `os` = '" , a1 ,"',"
      , "`phone_manufacture` = '",a2,"',"
      , "`phone_model` = '",a3,"',"
      , "`os_vers` = '",a4,"'");
   ```